# smartgit licence issue (Register smartgit)

Tags: 16.04, uninstall

I am facing issue with `SmartGit` in my Ubuntu 16.04, I have installed it few months ago and now when I am trying to use today it shows me this error, and I am unable to open my `SmartGit`. Help me in full uninstall so I can install again for non-commercial use. I have tried

```
sudo apt-get remove smartgit
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

after removing and new installation it shows me error again.

[image]

Comment: This is not an error. You are using a non-free product, and have to pay for a license after end of evaluation period.
You can try 'apt-get remove --purge smartgit'. This should remove all configurationfiles belonging to the package .. but really, pay for your software or find something that is free.

Comment: Its free for non commercial use. I usually use `SourceTree` but that is not available for `ubuntu`.